# Page not displaying correctly in IE7 div positioning?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, muse

First post.  Preface - Recently started web developing so don't have much experience with IE7.

Created a webpage using Adobe Muse for the first time because it's supposed to be fast for the design side.  Design was fast but having some weird issues displaying the page in IE7.  A div always jumps to the very top of the page whether the positioning is absolute or relative.  Not sure what is going on.  The page is found at

http://dealer.dealers2farmers.com/dealers/cherokeegarage/

There is a horizontal div that contains the "Search Inventory" and Google map that always jumps to the top of the page in IE7.

This is the CSS of the div

```
#horzBannerPosition

    {
    z-index: 2;
        width: 0.01px;
    top: -3px;
    margin-bottom: -3px;
    position: relative;
}
```

I thought the width was strange, Adobe Muse wrote most of this but it seems to work just fine with newer browsers.  Not sure why this jumps to the top of the page in IE7.  Any ideas?

Comment: does it even support ie7? When I'm looking at the page in ie7 mode (in ie9) the page looks like a hopeless mess with the problem you mention being the least of them.

Answer (score 0):

Ok with just a quick glance over, looks like you have a conflict with your z-indexing, your positioning, as well as using top. Remember for IE7, z-indexing actually starts at 0 and gets all messy from there (this may help: http://www.shawnpreisz.com/css/z-index-internet-explorer-7-ie7). Also careful with using classes and id's in the same tag. I would have to dedicate more time to this to check it out in full, but check out that article for the time being.